# awk в bash выводит не то число

Tags: awk

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему на консоль выводится другое число?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print 1844674407370955161}'
1844674407370955264
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `--bignum`:

```
awk --bignum 'BEGIN {print 1844674407370955161}'
```

Вывод:

> 1844674407370955161